# Two conda environments with same torch version show different torch.cuda.is_available

Tags: python, conda, virtualenv, torch

I have 2 different conda environments.  Using `conda list` shows both environments have

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
torch                     1.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

For each conda environment, I start the python interpreter from the cmd line and run:

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

For 1 environment, `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `true` and for the other it returns `false`.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Following up the answer, could you please add the output from `conda list cuda` in each environment?

Comment: I ended up deleted the environments.